# merge 2 sorted linked-list

Tags: merge, linked-list

what is wrong in my code?the method SortedMerge takehead of two linked list ,i have used node pointer z which will point to the node we are working on, pointer head which is initialized to point z,because in the end z will point to the last node ....i am returning the head of the final sorted merge list.

```
 struct node* SortedMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b) 
{
struct node* z=NULL;
struct node *head=z;
while(a!=NULL || b!=NULL)  
{
  if(a==NULL)
  {
    return(b);

    break;
}
else if(b==NULL)
{
    return(a);
    break;

}

if(a->data<b->data)
{
    struct node* newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=a->data;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    z=newnode;
    SortedMerge(a->next,b);
}
else if(a->data>b->data)
{
    struct node* newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data=b->data;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    z=newnode;
    SortedMerge(a,b->next);
}}
return (head) ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Concise code for you,

```
Node MergeLists(Node list1, Node list2) {
  if (list1 == null) return list2;
  if (list2 == null) return list1;

  if (list1.data < list2.data) {
    list1.next = MergeLists(list1.next, list2);
    return list1;
  } else {
    list2.next = MergeLists(list2.next, list1);
    return list2;
  }
}
```

See description [how it works](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/)